# How can I view a topic in a forum after submitting it?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm setting up a forum but I'm stuck at being able to actually view and respond to the topic. I have a form set up on my index page that allows me to create a topic and save it to a database. It saves the `title`, `message` and `author` of the topic and displays all topics by last post.

Here is my Topic Schema

```
const topicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  author: {
    type: String,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  posts: { type: String, ref: "Posts" },
  postCount: { type: Number, default: 1, required: true },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

Here's my GET that finds all topics and sorts them.

```
router.get("/", async function (req, res, next) {
  const [list_topic] = await Promise.all([
    Topic.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 }).exec(),
  ]);
  res.render("index", { list_topic });
});
```

I have some `ejs` code that displays all topics and allows me to be sent to the topic itself by its `id` when I click on its title.

```
<% list_topic.forEach(topic => { %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>
        <a href="/board/<%=topic.id %> "> <%=topic.title %> </a>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td><span> <%=topic.author %> </span></td>
  </tr>
<% }); %>
```

And here is my GET when I click on a topic

```
router.get("/:topicId", async function (req, res, next) {
  const topicId = req.params;
  console.log(topicId);

  const [list_posts] = await Promise.all([
    Topic.findOne({ id: topicId }).exec(),
  ]);

  res.render("topic", { topicId, list_posts });
});
```

I think this is what is messing me up because I keep getting a lot of `Page Not Found` with this one. What I'm trying to do is find a Topic by its `id` and match it to the `req.params`. When that happens the code should load whichever topic it finds and display its title, message content, author, etc. in a new page after I click on it. But for some reason it's not working.